# change a state variable from using another contract

Tags: solidity

There are 2 contracts. Contract A and Contract B. There is a mapping in Contract A you need to be updated from contract B.
Condition:The mapping should be updated only when called by Contract B, else revert.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

In contractA, store contractB's address and check if the msg.sender is contractB's address

```
function changeMap() external {
  require(msg.sender == _contractBAddress, 'address not match');
}
```

You can also create a [modifier](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)

```
modifier onlyContractB {
        require(
            msg.sender == _contractBAddress,
            "Only contractB can call this function."
        );
        _;
    }

function changeMap() onlyContractB {
   // do something
}
```